# a query improvement

Tags: mysql, search

Can somebody suggest me an improvement for the following query.

```
$q = "
    SELECT q. *
      FROM questions q, answers a
     WHERE q.questions LIKE '%".$str."%'
        OR a.answers   LIKE '%".$str."%'
       AND q.id = a.id_questions
  GROUP BY q.id
     LIMIT 10"
```

It is used in a search on a database with >100.000 questions and answers.

With less records works ok, but now...

Even with limit 10 the server gone away

Comment: which database server are you using?

Comment: Not to mention that using `LIKE '%string%'` searches mean indexes on those columns can't be used.

Comment: Are those WHERE clauses correct? Is the `q.id = a.id_questions` clause only relevant when the answer contains the specified string?

Comment: yes it is, but even if i remove that line the query still doesn't work

Comment: Isn't `FROM questions q, answers a` making cross join between the two tables?

Comment: @Bosak I think the `q.id = a.id_questions` clause is supposed to turn that into an INNER JOIN, but it doesn't because the WHERE clause isn't structured properly.

Comment: I find it generally easier to create real joins, rather than piling on more conditions. Use `WHERE` for filtering, not joining tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT     q.*
FROM       questions q
INNER JOIN answers a
ON         q.id = a.id_questions
WHERE      q.questions LIKE '%yourstring%'
OR         a.answers LIKE '%yourstring%'
GROUP BY   q.id
```

Comment: BTW: Do you sanitize your database inputs?